# General function for getting a view into an n-dimensional array (pseudocode)

Tags: multidimensional-array, indexing

Presume I have an N-dimensional array of dimensions `(N_i, N_j, N_k, ... N_n)`. For fast performance, this array is implemented in code as a flat array/list of length `N_i x N_j x N_k, ... x N_N`. For instance, if the array was 2-dimensional with dimensions `(M, K)` then it would be represented as a flat array of length `M x K`.

Let me term the n-dimensional array `n_arr` with dimensions `dims` and its backing flat array `f_arr`. If I wanted to return a view `n_arr[i]` into this array, e.g. `n_arr[0]`, if the array was a 2D array, then I have found that:

```
let start_index = i * dims[1]
let end_index = i * dims[1] + dims[1]
n_arr[i] = f_arr[start_index:end_index]
```

However, I have not been able to derive a formula for the 3D case or any higher-dimensional case. What would the general formula be to find the start and end indices for returning a view of an N-dimensional array?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution for this issue. To do this, I made a
class:

```
class Array:
    def __init__(data, shape):
        self.array = data
        self.dims = shape

    def ndims(self):
        return len(self.dims)
```

And a method:

```
fn get_flat_index(self, idx) {
    let mut i = 0;
    for j in 0..self.dims.len() {
        assert(idx[j] < self.dims[j]);
        if idx[j] >= self.dims[j] {
            print("Index {} is out of bounds for dimension {} with size {}", idx[j], j, self.dims[j])
            }
            i = i * self.dims[j] + idx[j];
        }
        i
}
```

Where `get_flat_index([M, N, K...J])` returns the flat index:

```
// 2d case
n_arr[i] = f_arr[get_flat_index(i, 0), get_flat_index(i, dims[1] - 1)

// 3d case
n_arr[i] = f_arr[get_flat_index(i, 0, 0), get_flat_index(i, dims[1] - 1, dims[2] - 1)

// N-d case
n_arr[i] = f_arr[get_flat_index(i, 0, 0, ... 0), get_flat_index(i, dims[n-1] - 1, dims[n-2] - 1, ... dims[n - n] - 1)
```

Using this I implemented my `index()` function:

```
fn index(self, idx) {
    let start_index_slice = vec![0; self.ndims()];
    let end_index_slice = vec![0; self.ndims()];
    start_index_slice[0] = idx;
    for i in 1..self.ndims() {
        end_index_slice[i] = self.dims[i] - 1;
    }
    let start_index = self.get_index(start_index_slice);
    let end_index = self.get_index(end_index_slice);
    self.array[start_index:end_index + 1]
}
```